# Is there a way to open any activity

Tags: debugging, android-studio, android-activity

i'm currently testing an app, and i need to test a specific screen, however i can't access it normally. Is there a way to jump directly to that activity? I tried that Launch Options on the Configuration screens. But it says "The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter". Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your manifest activity. Change your activity name and theme.

```
 <activity
        android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME"
        android:theme="YOUR_THEME">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Just one more thing, is it possible to launch this activity and a method within that activity?

Comment: Ok, for example, that Activity has a method showHello(). Is it possible to launch that activity AND launch the showHello() method at the same time

Comment: To avoid creating another question. Is there a way to do this in Xcode as well?